# Using 2 scripts in HTML: first javascript won't work after second javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 scripts in my HTML and I found out that last script overrides the first script so the FIRST script won't work and the last works perfectly. What's the solution?

Javascripts:

```
//First js
function myFunction(x) {
   var opacity = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
   var el = document.getElementById("p1");
     if (el.style.opacity !== undefined) {
       el.style.opacity = opacity;
    } else {
       alert("Your browser doesn't support this!");
}
}

//Second js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
     if (x.className === "topnav") {
       x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
}
}
```

Comment: Don't reuse the same function name.

Comment: oh wait, "myFunction" is the name of the script?

Comment: No it is the name you have given to the function.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, Thank you both!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, BlecKent! Sorry for the downvotes on this question, they were undeserved. I hope the answers are comments are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both scripts are loading perfectly. There is no conflict caused by the act of linking and loading them.

The problem arises because **both scripts define a function with the same name**. The browser considers the second definition an "update", and simply forgets about the first, thinking you intend to replace it.

Simply give the functions different names. In programming, it's good practice to name the functions according to their behavior, so that later you can easily recognize them.

For example, you could name the first function `setOpacity`, and the second function `makeResponsive`.

First JS file:

```
function setOpacity(x) {
   var opacity = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
   var el = document.getElementById("p1");
     if (el.style.opacity !== undefined) {
       el.style.opacity = opacity;
    } else {
       alert("Your browser doesn't support this!");
    }
}
```

Second JS file:

```
function makeResponsive() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
     if (x.className === "topnav") {
       x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your long explanation!

Comment: Sorry again, giving another name than "myFunction", wont't work even one of them. Do I need to add something?

Comment: When are these functions being called? _Calling_ a function is the act of running the code contained inside it. Somewhere in the rest of your code, it should say `myFunction()`, or `myFunction(x)`. Replace that with  `makeResponsive()` or `setOpacity(x)`, reflecting their new names